# player animation starts from first bug

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

hello iam using a blendspace to make an animation the blend space repeats itself from the start as shown
and when i try to run the player animation bugs and starts from start as shown
what should i do?
link videos below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g3W7U5u5kLqCVigjUavMNUBOiYsq-Mf2/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fRsgRCJmd8_9k2X7MlUuz524gpFXQL8A/view?usp=sharing
nothing i don't know what to do

Comment: Please describe your problem. and attempt to give a **minimal** code example of the problem. This requirement forces re-examination of the code before posting, many times leading to the solution before asking. This is not text code per se, but could you digest your problem into a couple of screen shots of your best guess as to the problem's sources?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the way you imported animation. If you download animations from website like mixamo.com and you don't want it to loop, make sure you check "In place" option.